# Ajax Class error with accessing class variable in onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am currently writing a JavaScript Ajax class and have encountered an error. In the function processRawData() I can't seem to access the class variable xhr by using this.xhr. I get "cannot read property of readyState of undefined. I have currently fixed this problem by passing in the xhr value when setting the reference to the onreadystatechange function however that seems unneeded as I should be able to access the xhr value without doing so.

```
function Ajax()
{
    this.xhr = this.createXmlHttpRequest();
}

Ajax.prototype.createXmlHttpRequest = function()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("Couldn't create XmlHttpRequest : " + e);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            throw new Error("Couldn't create XmlHttpRequest : " + e);
        }
    }
}

Ajax.prototype.request = function(type, url, params, dataType, callback)
{
    if (this.xhr.readyState === 0 || this.xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var isGetWithParams = (type === "GET") ? ((params !== null) ? url + params : url) : url
        this.xhr.open(type, isGetWithParams, true);

        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = this.processRawData(dataType, callback);

        var passInParams = (type === "GET") ? null : ((params !== null) ? params : null);
        this.xhr.send(passInParams);
    }
}

Ajax.prototype.processRawData = function(dataType, callback)
{
     return function()
     {
        if (this.xhr.readyState === 4 && this.xhr.status === 200) {
            switch (dataType) {
                case "text":
                    var data = this.xhr.responseText;
                    break;
                case "xml":
                default:
                    var data = this.xhr.responseXML;
            }

            callback(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should know that the purpose of the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` branch is solely to support IE versions 5 and 6 (later versions are OK with `XMLHttpRequest`). Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem might be because in processRawData() you are returning another function and referencing this.xhr.readyState, but 'this' now references the returning function and not the Ajax class. Try:

```
Ajax.prototype.processRawData = function(dataType, callback){

var that = this; //'that' references the current Ajax instance

 return function()
 {
    if (that.xhr.readyState === 4 && that.xhr.status === 200) {...
```

Comment: I actually suspected that might have been the problem. I could have sworn it didn't work when I took it out of the function before. Thanks for the help!